# Выполнение php-скрипта через крон

Tags: php, cron

Команда

```js
/usr/bin/php /var/www/skbonus/data/www/beta.skbonus.ru/cron_run.php delivery >/dev/null 2>&1
```

выдает 255,права стоят 755.
Если в скрипте оставить только

```js
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

выводит пустую страницу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно проверить конфигурацию cli для php (файл php.ini) на предмет safe_mode=On

Также стоит проверить доступ к файлу php от того пользователя, от которого создается CRON задание.

Ещё стоит сначала проверить запуск в SSH:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/skbonus/data/www/beta.skbonus.ru/cron_run.php delivery
```

так как 255 - это скорее всего PID процесса.

Проверьте кодировку файла, может быть, что вначале стоит BOM символ, из-за чего php отказывается его запускать.

Проверьте правильность указания пути для php-cli выводом команды:

```
which php
```

Comment: Exited with return code = 255